# Standalone directive modification using LXML and Python

Tags: python, xml, maven, lxml, pom.xml

I have modified a POM.xml and iam trying to write the changes to the same file , however , in my original POM.xml i had `standalone='no'` directive , but in my modified file i'am getting `standalone='yes'`.

Declaration in POM.xml example-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
```

My code -

```
et = etree.ElementTree(root)
et.write("C:\Temp\python workspace\pom1.xml",pretty_print=True,
xml_declaration = True , encoding="UTF-8",standalone="no")
```

Could anybody point out out what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an abandoned question so I'm leaving the answer for people from the future like myself.

Standalone is a boolean (True/False) meaning standalone='no' == standalone='yes'.
http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.DocInfo-class.html

Problem:

```
et.write("C:\Temp\python workspace\pom1.xml",pretty_print=True,
xml_declaration = True , encoding="UTF-8",standalone="no")
```

Solution:

```
et.write("C:\Temp\python workspace\pom1.xml",pretty_print=True,
xml_declaration = True , encoding="UTF-8",standalone=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try as below-

```
from lxml import etree


data = """            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/dist-binary.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>standalone-sample</finalName>
                    <standalone>yes</standalone>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id><!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase><!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal><!-- goals == mojos -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(data)

for mytag in tree.xpath("//standalone"):
    mytag.text = "no"
print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: @Slslam pls have a look at the updated directive example in pom.xml, i dont have a tag named standalone in POM.xml as mentioned by you in your proposed solution .

Comment: Could you post it here?

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>